# Created an entry in rails console, but app has no idea it exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I entered

```
SiteData.create(site_name: "My Site", url: "http://mysite.com")
```

in the console, SiteData being one of my models.  Now I can write SiteData.find(1) and it will echo back the entry.  Great!

I'm using the db table to store all the info about my site, such as the name, the url, the Facebook page, the Google Plus pages, etc.  SO I need to access it on every page.  Okay, I'll use before_filter in the application controller to make this work, right?

So I went into my app, and in the Application controller, I wrote

```
  before_filter :add_site_data
  def add_site_data
    @site_data = SiteData.find(1)
  end
```

And I get an error:  "Couldn't find SiteData with id=1"

What now????

This might not be the best way to do this.  I am brand new to rails.  But I'm totally stuck and have no idea what's going on or why here.  I installed Postgres locally today and set up the test and dev dbs, but it seems to be working fine since I can still create/read/update/destroy entries from the console.

Please help!  I'm going nuts here.  I am using Rails 4.0.

Comment: First of all, you should create persisting objects in console by using `SiteData#create`. I have never seen that syntax you used.

Comment: Okay, I'm doing this a much less stupid way for this particular info, but I still would like to know what went wrong here because it will be helpful for the future.

Comment: I got it from the online rails tutorial:  http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial

Also, it's the same as used in Rails for Zombies.  I also just quite the console and re-entered it, and it's still there, so it seems to be persistent.  I don't know how to look at the tables in postgres directly.  :(  I've tried searching for that.

Comment: Could you point me to a specific line in there? Anyway, I would ask you to try it my way and then tell me what happens.

Comment: A second guess would be that you may be running console in a different environment from your `rails server`. What do you get from `RAILS_ENV`?

Comment: From the ROR tutorial, here's a line you can find:  User.create(name: "A Nother", email: "another@example.org")

Comment: Exactly, it's using `create` just like I said.

Comment: I tried your way.  It didn't create an entry at all.  It just echoed back what the columns are without adding anything.

Comment: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveResource/Base/create/class

Comment: Let me be perfectly clear here: `SiteData.create(site_name: "My Site", url: "http://mysite.com")`

Comment: development.  Oh, crap, I typo'd above--sorry.  I did use SiteData.create.  I'm so tired right now...

Comment: To clarify:  I wrote SiteData.create(blah: "blah") from the outset.  And yet my app has no knowledge of SiteData.find(1)--none.

Comment: Are you, by any chance, starting your console in `--sandbox` mode?

Comment: Nope.  And I exited and entered the console again and called .find again, and it still worked, so it's in the database somewhere.  Maybe I screwed up setting up the database??????

Comment: It's really guesswork. Your problem isn't reproducible with the info you provided.

Comment: I don't understand how I could access the database just fine from the console and not from the app.  I just don't know how it's possible.

Comment: If you're running your application in test or production mode, then you'll be using a different database and you'd experience this. Did you see the question about RAILS_ENV?

Comment: Yes, and it's being run in development.  I double-checked.

Comment: Resetting the server solved everything.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an inexperienced user who forgot to reboot the server. Too localized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resetting the server fixed it.

If you know you're making entries in your database that aren't reflected when you run your app, reset the server.